# Setting environment variables on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, operating-system, environment-variables, macos-catalina

In which file should I set *environment variables* on macOS Catalina?

I have already tried the `.bash_profile` file but it does't work.

Answer (score 2):

For Zsh shell, type this in your terminal:

```
$ echo 'export ENV_VAR=value' >> ~/.zshenv
```

Then restart your terminal and type `printenv` to confirm if it's there.

To view the value of your env_var type the following:

```
$ echo $ENV_VAR
```

Comment: is it case sensitive? thx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can set it in your `~/.bashrc`

Secondly, you need to restart your shell, or run `source ~/.bashrc` to activate it.

Thirdly, make sure you are using `bash`. e.g. if using `zsh` then you need `~/.zshrc`.

Lastly, ensure your code in the file is correct. e.g. `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tom/.cargo/bin"` as a line in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I've set in zprofile and it works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

macOS Catalina and later macOSs do not use the bash shell as default anymore. Instead zsh is used.

Go to your user's home directory. In the shell you type `cd ~/.zprofile`, if you prefer a GUI you go to the Finder, then to the home icon and your user name. There you press `command shift .` to view hidden files and folders.
Open the file `.zprofile` either using TextEdit or another text editor.

Add a line in the following format:

```
export VARIABLES_NAME=value
```

Don't use quotes around the value even if it is a string.
Save the file, open a new terminal, and type `echo $VARIABLE_NAME` to confirm the variable's persistance.